Polars - How to extract last non-null value on a given column
I'd like to perform the following:
Input:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1,15,None,20,None]
})

Output:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1,15,None,20,None],
    "b": [0,14,None,5,None]
})

That is, from:



A




1


15


None


20


None



to:



A
B




1
0


15
14


None
None


20
5


None
None



So, what it does:

If the value of "A" is null, then value of B (output column) is also Null
If "A" has some value, please retrieve the last Non-Null value in "A", and then subtract the current value in "A" with the previous Non-Null value

I'd like to perform this in python's polars dataframe library, but I can't seem to find a solution.
I've tried the following question:
How to select the last non-null value from one column and also the value from another column on the same row in Polars?
But unfortunately, this does not answer the original problem, since the question performs an aggregation of an entire column, and then takes the last value of that column.
What I'd like to do is not to aggregate an entire column, but simply to subtract a current value with a previous non-null value.
I have also tried to use rolling:
df = df.with_row_index().rolling(
    index_column = 'index',
    period = '???i').agg(pl.col("A").last())

But, of course, that does not work because the occurence of Null Values cannot be determined (i.e. it is not periodic, so I don't know how many indexes before the current entry contains a non-null value in "A").
Does anyone knows how to do so?
Thanks!

You can use a combination of shift and forward_fill to get the last non-null value.
So with your input, this looks like
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 15, None, 20, None]
})
df.with_columns(
    # current row value for "a" minus the last non-null value
    # as the first row has no previous non-null value,
    # fill it with the first value (1)
    (
        pl.col("a") - 
        pl.col("a").shift(fill_value=pl.col("a").first()).forward_fill()
    ).alias("b")
)
# shape: (5, 2)
# ┌──────┬──────┐
# │ a    ┆ b    │
# │ ---  ┆ ---  │
# │ i64  ┆ i64  │
# ╞══════╪══════╡
# │ 1    ┆ 0    │
# │ 15   ┆ 14   │
# │ null ┆ null │
# │ 20   ┆ 5    │
# │ null ┆ null │
# └──────┴──────┘


You can avoid when().then by setting fill_value=pl.col('a').first() for shift: df.with_columns((pl.col("a") - pl.col("a").shift(fill_value=pl.col('a').first()).forward_fill()).alias('b')).

Thank you, you're right. Will update shortly as that is better. Much appreciated

Are they actually equivalent? If null is the 2nd value they will produce different outputs. (fill_value=0 in the when/then did seem somewhat faster than fill_null(0) for larger frames in my testing)

@jqurious: thanks. Not sure about null as 2nd value -- what's your a in this case? Issue is with None as first (e.g., using {"a": [None, 15, None, 20, None]}). Suppose we need: fill_value=pl.col('a').drop_nulls().first(). I figured first would return first non None value, but that's not true). Incidentially, fill_value=0 instead of fill_null(0) for when/then also doesn't always get required output.

@ouroboros1 Sorry for the noise - I had a paren in the wrong place (causing different output) and came to the wrong conclusion.
